# richtextbox delete specified line

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I want to delete specified words from richtextbox that have similiar words with my .txt file and then print it into another richtextfile. this is my source code

```
Using line As New StreamReader("stoplist.txt")
        While Not line.EndOfStream
            filter.Add(line.ReadLine)
        End While
    End Using

    For Each words As String In filter
        If words.Contains(filter.ToString) Then
            filter.Remove(words)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'How I print the result into richtextbox
```

I don't know how to print it again into another richtextbox. May be my source code also need some edit?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "vb.net". That's what we use tags for on [so].